# Android OnItemClickListener in list view not working

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm have made a tab activity which works fine when i click on specific tab i extend the list activity and am also getting the list view but i'm not able to make the items in list clickable. code:

```
package com.infra.android.views;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class TopNewsActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        String xml = XMLfunctions.getTopNewsXML();
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

        int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

        if((numResults <= 0)){
            Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this, "No Result Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            finish();
        }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
            map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
            map.put("title", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "title"));
            mylist.add(map);            
        }       

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, new String[] { "title"}, new int[] { R.id.item_title});

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            }
        });
    }
}
```

when i click on the item it should probably give the id of the clicked item but it is not working.

Comment: what content in your listview? like any imageview or checkbox

Comment: @Ayudh I have normal text which i want to make clickable

Comment: please define "not working". Does it throw an `Exception`? What does your LogCat say? When in debug mode, what values the `o: HashMap` hold? Are they correct?

Answer (score 5):

For ListView,

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContainlistItems);
lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
```

and In XML file, make sure that for Textview inside list item set focusable false

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: This "ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContainlistItems);" wont work as he has extended ListView...

Comment: @Kartik: Why shouldn't it? You can always parse the object type to the parent class...

Comment: @WarrenFaith : It was not working for me. When i asked SO developers, they only told me that you cannot use  "ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContainlistItems);" if you are extending ListView. Even they told me that it will always return null.

Comment: @Kartik: test it and you will see it works. Working sample: normal Activity class (not ListActivity), a xml layout with a ListView inside and you can easily get the reference to it. Even if you create a customized ListView... Can you show me the question, where you get the "null" answer?

Comment: @WarrenFaith : ok i got it what you are telling. But i want to extend ListView. And i wanted to display simple list view with only one String per item. how can i ?... for this : what i got from SO was -> create instance of ListView like lv=getListView(), dont use the findViewById(....);

Comment: @Kartik: Both should work, the first way only works in ListActivity (but also with a custom ListView) the second one works in every Activity type... if you want to get more details, start a question... comments are the wrong place for that :)

Comment: @WarrenFaith ok. I am starting a new question.

Answer (score 3):

u can use

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
     lvlList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvlList);
lvlList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
```

You have missed the `@Override`.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in android with showing dialogs and toasts in subactivities, so your code have to work fine but to make toast try this:

```
Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this.getParent(), "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your adapter you inflate the main layout for every list item. That should be changed to an itemrenderer's layout.

Since you already have the solution for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754081/android-onitemclicklistener-in-listview-not-working/5754282#5754282), you should mark it solved either by accepting any of these answers, or by answering it yourself with the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this for some time before I figured out that `areAllItemsEnabled` and `isEnabled` in my costum `ListAdapter` where set to false.