# Android onItemClicklistener in listview not working

Tags: android

Can anyone help me out with my problem. I have a TabActivity each tab is on touch opens a new activity which extends ListActivity at this time i get the list of desired items which i want to make clickable by using OnItemClickListener.

i'm attaching my **main.xml** please go through it and let me know if there are any changes required

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"/>
            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/item_title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class TopNewsActivity extends ListActivity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        String xml = XMLfunctions.getTopNewsXML();
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

        int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

        if ((numResults <= 0))
        {
            Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this, "No Result Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
        map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
        map.put("name", "Naam:" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
        map.put("Score", "Score: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "score"));
        mylist.add(map);            
    }       

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] { "name", "Score" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        /*lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getOnItemClickListener();

                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewsDetails.class);
                i.putExtra("content_id", o.get("id"));
                i.putExtra("title", o.get("title"));
                startActivity(i);
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            }
        });*/

        final OnItemClickListener myClickListener = new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getOnItemClickListener();

                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewsDetails.class);
                i.putExtra("content_id", o.get("id"));
                i.putExtra("title", o.get("naam"));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(myClickListener);
    }
}
```

**TabActivity**

```
 public class InfralineTabWidget extends TabActivity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TopNewsActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("topNews").setIndicator("Top News", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_news)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, PowerActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("power").setIndicator("Power", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_power)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}

 }
```

**ListPlaceHolder.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**XMLFunction.java**

```
 package com.infra.android.views;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.StringReader;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.text.CharacterIterator;
 import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XMLfunctions {

public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){

    Document doc = null;

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    return doc;

}


/** Returns element value
  * @param elem element (it is XML tag)
  * @return Element value otherwise empty String
  */
 public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node kid;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return kid.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /*Start Parsing Top News XML*/
 public static String getTopNewsXML(){   
        String line = null;

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://p-xr.com/xml");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }

        return line;

}


public static int numResults(Document doc){     
    Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
    int res = -1;

    try{
        res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
    }catch(Exception e ){
        res = -1;
    }

    return res;
}

public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return XMLfunctions.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}   

   }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of one of your `ListActivities` with the implementation of `OnItemClickListener`? thank you.

Comment: @rekaszeru I have added the code for ListActivity

Comment: Please see my post, and if there are exceptions in your LogCat, share them as well. Thanks!

Comment: Start debugging from displaying Toast message inside your item click listener and check whether its being called on onclick or not.

Comment: @Kartik I click on the item nothing is happenning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must get `ClassCastException` and if not that, at least `NullPointerException` because of the following line in your listener's code:

```
HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getOnItemClickListener();
```

You should change it to

```
HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position);
```

in case that you are trying to access the underlying object of the list item renderer.

**Edit**

I've just tried out this application, and it works on my end (with dummy data, classes, etc.) 
What i've changed though, is

```
final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.main, 
        new String[] { "title" }, new int[] { R.id.item_title });
setListAdapter(adapter);

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position);

        Intent i = new Intent(TopNewsActivity.this, NewsDetails.class);
        i.putExtra("content_id", o.get("id"));
        i.putExtra("title", o.get("title"));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

**Edit 2**

Rookie mistake focusing on the symptoms as we're sure the problem is there... Not that there wasn't, the notes above are standing.

But only when adopting the classes and layouts shared above, i realized, that you are actually using your `TabView`'s layout as an itemrenderer for the list inside your `TabView`...

That `main.xml` shouldn't contain those two `TextViews`, they should be in a separate xml file (say: **`list_item.xml`**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_title" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:padding="2dp" android:textSize="20dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" android:textSize="13dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and your **`main.xml`** should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

finally, when you initialize your list adapter, you should change it to use this `list_item.xml`:

```
final ListAdapter adapter =
    new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] 
        { "name", "Score" }, new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });
```

and that's it.

Now it works, and doesn't have a whole new `TabView` (without any tabs) in each of your list items, neither has extra, useless and invisible `TextViews` in your main layout.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when using RatingBar.

In my case I had to remove focus from the RatingBar using `android:isIndicator="true"`.

I see a lot of similar questions about ListView in Android. In general people are using some widget in their layout which overrides the default ListView click handling.

My answer is to check all widgets are not intercepting click events.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Edited File :

```
 public class TopNewsActivity extends ListActivity {

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


String xml = XMLfunctions.getTopNewsXML();
Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);

int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

if((numResults <= 0)){
    Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this, "No Result Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    finish();
}

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    

    Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
    map.put("id", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "id"));
    map.put("title", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "title"));
    mylist.add(map);            
}       

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, new String[] { "title"}, new int[] { R.id.item_title});



final ListView lv = getListView();
setListAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        //HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inside onItemClick",Toast_LONG).show();
        /*  
        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewsDetails.class);
        i.putExtra("content_id", o.get("id"));
        i.putExtra("title", o.get("title"));
        startActivity(i);*/
    }
});



}

}
```

Comment: @Rahul : ok see the edited answer and tell me is it working or not.

Comment: @kartik Still nothing is happening onItemClick not working the debugger by-passes the OnItemClick function

Comment: @Rahul : I used the same code in  my demo application n it was working. can you please upload your all files or project somewhere ?.

Comment: @Kartik Have a look the all necessary files are there now hope you can help me out

Comment: @Rahul : what is XMLfunctions ?..I am getting error in this. you have not uploaded somthing here.

Comment: @kartik i've updated the XMLFunctions also you just have to change the url's in it

Comment: @Rahul : what type of url should i write there ?

Comment: @kartik : It is showing the results i.e. data is being fetched. It will only show no data when there is no net connection which is not possible in your case.
Use this url in XMLFunctions.java : http://p-xr.com/xml/

Comment: @Rahul : yes i am here. i am still getting "No Data" in the tab..solving that now

Answer (score 0):

here's a reason that bit me recently: if you add a clicklistener to the view returned by your adapter, it masks the longclick behavior....